# Setting button name without using the word "self"

Tags: objective-c

UIButton * button = [self valueForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"buttonA"];

Is there a way to do the same thing without having to use the word "self"?

Comment: what's the issue with "self"? is it disturbing u ?

Comment: I'm trying to use this code in a C++ function (using objective-C++). C++ functions can't use "self".

Comment: then explain ur question well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` is the current instance of the class.

And this is the best way.

Other than self, you need to create yet another instance of the object and use that object.

```
MyClass *classObject=[MyClass new];
UIButton * button = [classObject valueForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"buttonA"];
```

#### You should not do this way.